# Compute $\frac{1+\theta}{1+\theta+\theta^2}$ in $\Bbb{Q}(\theta)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

So im told to compute $(1+\theta)(1+\theta+\theta^2)$ and $\frac{1+\theta}{1+\theta+\theta^2}$ where $\theta$ is a root of $p(x)=x^3-2x-2$ in some extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. I got for the first part:

\begin{align}
(1+\theta)(1+\theta+\theta^2)&= \theta^3 + 2 \theta^2 + 2 \theta +1\\\\
&= 2 \theta^2 + 4 \theta + 3
\end{align}

But for the second part, do I write it as $(1+ \theta)(1+\theta+\theta^2)^{-1}$ and compute the inverse? If so, I did the long division and have

$$\theta^3-2 \theta -2=(\theta^2+\theta+1)(\theta-1)-2 \theta - 1$$
where do I go from here?

Comment: But $p(\theta)=0$ thus $\theta^3=2 \theta+2$ where could i have gone wrong:?? @coudy

Comment: We can compute inverses by the Extended Euclidean algorithms - just like for integers - see the linked dupe.

Comment: that not the same question @BillDubuque ....

Comment: Doesn't matter - the same method works here.

Comment: **Or** by [inverse reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242), let $\,g\!=\!\theta^3-2\theta-2,\  f\!=\!\theta^2+\theta+1$. By Bezout $\,af+bg = 1$ and we first compute $\bmod f\!:\ b \equiv g^{-1}\,$ as follows, using $\,\color{#0a0}{\theta^3 = 1}$
$$\bmod f\!:\,\ \color{#c00}b\equiv \dfrac{1}{g}=\dfrac{1}{\color{#0a0}{\theta^3}-2\theta-2} \equiv \dfrac{-1}{2\theta+1}\equiv\color{#c00}{\dfrac{2\theta+1}3},\  {\rm by}\ \ 2\theta+1 = \sqrt{-3}$$

hence $\,af+bg = 1\Rightarrow \bmod g\!:\ f^{-1}\equiv a\equiv  \dfrac{1-\color{#c00}b\:\!g}f\equiv (-2\theta^2+\theta+5)/3\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply the denominator by $a\theta^2+b\theta+c$ then you get

\begin{align*}
(1+\theta+\theta^2)(a\theta^2+b\theta+c)=a\theta^4+(a+b)\theta^3+(a+b+c)\theta^2+(b+c)\theta+c
\end{align*}
but since $\theta^3=2\theta+2$ this can be rewritten as
$$(3 a+b+c)\theta^2 + (4 a+3b+c)\theta + 2 a+ 2 b  + c$$
now you want a constant/rational denominator, thus you want the $\theta,\theta^2$ terms gone.

By solving the linear system you deduce that can pick $a=2,b=-1,c=-5$ and obtain a denominator equal to $-3$ and you are done.

Comment: what?! how and where did this come from to do lol

Comment: whats the intuition behind this i mean..

Comment: Sorry, my original idea was too simplistic.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Btw, you should show how you computed the solutions for $\,a,b,c\,$ rather than pull them out of a hat like magic.

Comment: @BillDubuque I assumed that given the question, explicitly solving a linear system would not be of much interested to the OP. That said I shall avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following direct but frustrated way: assume that $(1+\theta )(1+\theta +\theta^2)^{-1} =p(\theta)$ for some polynomial $p(\theta)$ of degree not greater than or equal to $2$. Multiply both sides by $(1+\theta +\theta^2)$ gives us an identity $1+\theta =p(\theta)(1+\theta +\theta^2)$. Let $p(\theta )=a+b\theta +c\theta^2$, by plugging in this $p(\theta)$ and using the given relation to reduce to polynomials of degree at most $2$, you get a linear system, whose solution tells you the conclusion.

Comment: where do I use that my given $p$ evaluated at $\theta$ is $0$?

Comment: @anonymous It's not the same polynomial in the relation, but just assume the answer is this polynomial.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).